# Android RadioButton and Button one ClickEvent

Tags: android, button, dynamic, onclick

I have an application that has different component (radiobutton,checkbox,button vs).And I created dynamically all of them but now there is one problem ;

I cant create event to all when they created.I need a advice for one click event all of them.

forgive me my english little bad but thank you in advance.
please help me

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. What do you want to do specifically?

Comment: You want to have a single `OnClickListener` that connects to all of your components?  Just create a subclass of `View.OnClickListener` and add that to all of your components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to implement onclicklistener in your activity ? After that, for all components ,you should set their onclicklistener.But there is an important point.Radiobutton and checkbox has their own listeners, "setOnCheckedChangeListener" . I think you should use it. But if you want ,you can implement OnClickListener like this.

```
public class myActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

            button1.setOnClickListener(this);
            checkbox1.setOnClickListener(this);
            radiobuton1.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //You can listen "click event" of button1 ,checkbox1 and radiobutton1 here.

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RadioButton rb ; 
CheckBox cb;
Button btn;

public void MultiEvent (int clickId ){
    if (clickId == 0) {

    }else if (clickId == 1) {

    }else if (clickId == 2) {

    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int clickId = 0;
            MultiEvent (clickId );
        }
    });

    rb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int clickId = 1;
            MultiEvent (clickId );
        }
    });

    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int clickId = 2;
            MultiEvent (clickId );
        }
    });


}
```